# Why do users have to enter a 7-digit twitter PIN to grant my application access?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, oauth

I am implementing some ruby on rails code tweet stuff for my users.  I am creating the proper oauth link...something like

```
http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=y2RkuftYAEkbEuIF7zKMuzWN30O2XxM8U9j0egtzKv
```

But after my test account grants access to twitter, it pulls up a page saying "You've successfully granted access to . Simply return to  and enter the following PIN to complete the process. 1234567"

I have no idea where the user should enter this PIN and why they have to do that.  I don't think this should be a necessary step.  Twitter should be redirecting the user to the callback URL I provided in the application settings.  Does anyone know why this is happening?

**UPDATE**
I found [this article](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Sign-in-with-Twitter) that states I need to send my users to this URL (note "authenticate" instead of "authorize"):

```
http://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=y2RkuftYAEkbEuIF7zKMuzWN30O2XxM8U9j0egtzKv
```

I made the change but Twitter redirects the user to the authorize path after he clicks "Allow" which then gives him the 7 digit PIN again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[OAuth 1.0a](http://oauth.net/advisories/2009-1) added the PIN to solve a [social engineering attack to which OAuth 1.0 was vulnerable](http://oauth.net/advisories/2009-1).  But the PIN is only necessary to be entered manually by the user if your application is a desktop/iphone app.  If it's a web app the PIN should flow automatically as part of the browser redirects and the user shouldn't have to see or enter this.

So if your app is a web app, then there's a bug either in your OAuth library or your use of it.  If your app is a desktop app, this is a "feature" designed to keep your users safe.

Comment: My app is a web app.  According to the Twitter docs, taking the user to /oauth/authenticate will tell Twitter that my app is a web app and to include the PIN automatically.  However, after clicking Allow, Twitter is redirecting to /oauth/authorize which is the path for Desktop apps.  I don't see how I can change anything on my side to fix this.

Comment: Well, considering that no other Twitter web app has this problem, it's gotta be on the client side.  Now, it might also be that you have your twitter.com/oauth_client setup for your web app to be a desktop app.  I recommend double-checking that Twitter knows that your consumer_key is associated with a web app and not a desktop app.  Failing that, I return to "it's a bug in your library or the way you're using it."

Comment: You were right about an oauth bug.  Getting oauth 0.3.4 fixed my application.  The issue is with oauth 0.3.5

Answer (score 6):

If you don't specify an `oauth_callback` parameter with the URL you'd like the user redirected to when they accept, it will default to the pin-based authentication mechanism. Using `oauth_callback=oob` will also trigger the pin-based authentication flow.

Comment: that did not work for me.  for twitter, they have a callback parameter you can set in the application settings...so i am not sure sending a URL param will make a difference but thanks for the response

Comment: @Tony i have the same problem too. Somebody know the cause for this error.

Answer (score 1):

Just log in to you twitter account and edit the application to **change from Desktop to Browser** Everybody is doing that mistake including myself.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when I use the

`config.gem "twitter", :version => "0.6.12"`

twitter redirects fine and don't show the pin

but when I use the newer gem version

```
config.gem "twitter", :version => "0.9.2"
```

it always shows the pin.

This definitely needs further investigation, and may be solved with further configuration
that I didn't do with the newer GEM.